# Formdata send to java controller get 415 error

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

here is my code,I am using angular and spring mvc . Please suggest me the way

```
vm.upload= function(state_cd){

             fd= new FormData();
             fd.append("mst.distCd", dist_cd);
            call(fd);
         });
     }

    function call(fd){
         $http({
            type: "POST",
                url: "./WQF00069/update.app",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,

                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},

                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,

            }).success(function(data) {
                Flash.create('info', ' Update Success Fully ', 'large-text');
            }).error(function(response){ 
                 console.dir(response);
                 Flash.create('danger','There is a  Problem.Contact With Administrator', 'large-text');

         });
    }
```

After send to my controller get get 415 error

Comment: Have a look at backend how to receive the parameter.

Comment: i am using java spring to receive the data

Comment: If you receive the data via `@RequestBody` annotation, it would not be resolved correctly. Also you can have a try with the @Murat 's answer.